# Auto-Decrement the month of a year

Tags: vba, excel

I would like a table that looks like this:

[image]

Now that on its own is not very complicating however I would like excel to auto-decrement the month column so that every month, the month at position 0 is the present month and the rest move down one position. So when a month is suppose to reach position 18 it gets removed from the table?
Does that make sense?

Comment: It does make sense. Try recording a macro while setting up a new month. You should be able to write this yourself. If you get stuck, post your code and ask for help on the part that isn't working.

Comment: I am clue less as to were to start, could you please post an answer.

Comment: Would you like the whole row to move down, or just change the contents of the first 18 cells of the sheet? Meaning, do you want to move things around, or just recalculate what "this month" and "previous month" and so on is?

Comment: check my answer @LasseV.Karlsen. It works 100% and upvote if you agree!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have done:

```
= DATE(YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW())-O599, 1)
```

O599 is the location of the Number column that starts with 0. So as we look further down the table it subtracts the number indicated in the Number column from the current month!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do that simply with formulas. For the first date use this formula in B2

`=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1`

Now in B3 use this formula copied down

`=EDATE(B2,-1)`

custom format all dates as mmm-yyyy

Dates will update automatically on first of every month - the underlying date value is the first of each month but it will just display with month and year

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the month for 18 monts ago.  You can then create a macro that will copy this down and have the month increment.

```
MyMonth = DateAdd("m", -18, Date)
```

This is similar to what you need:

```
Selection.Copy
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A20"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A20").Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Sheet layout:

`A2:A20`: number of the moth (0..18)
B2:     `=EDATE(NOW();-A2)`
Cell format: `mmm-yyyy` (or something else according to the needs)

The formula is copied down.